# How can I report on errors coming from an AngularJS $q.all?

Tags: angularjs

My code looks like this:

```
    $q.all([
        this.getData(EnumGetData.ContentStatus),
        this.getData(EnumGetData.ContentType),
        this.getData(EnumGetData.UserProfile),
    ])
        .then((results) => {
            self.contentStatus = results[1];
            self.contentType = results[2];
            self.userProfile = results[3];
        }, function () {
            alert // 
        });
```

My getData function parameters are like this:

```
        getData(controller) {
```

My getData function return this if there is an error:

```
        .error((data, status, headers, config) {
            defer.reject();
        });
```

What I would like to do is to give an alert message if the $q.all fails. Can anyone suggest how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plunker showing what you need to do http://plnkr.co/KUPTjpbVBgMhWUWrh1YI.

You can pass an error message like this: deferred.reject('ERROR MESSAGE') and then you can catch it in the error handler of the then.

```
function getData(input) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.reject(input);
    }, 2000);

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  $q.all([getData(1),
    getData(2),
    getData(3)
  ]).then(function success(data) {
    console.log('should not get here');
  }, function(error) {
    alert(error);
  });
```